# Javascript coding for zopim live chat not visible in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, livechat

In my site pages, I used a javascript coding for live chat from zopim. This works fine in chrome and Firefox. The live chat window is displaying and can able to chat with that window.

But in IE the chat window is not visible. But when using inspect element in IE it highlights the div for the chat window. I tried some other coding from zopim. But I didn't get the result in IE.

I dont know what is the problem. Anybody can help me to solve this issue for live chat. The coding I used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sample test zopim</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
 </head>
<body>
Sample test Zopim
<!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script--> <script type="text/javascript">
        window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s= d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set. _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8'); $.src='//cdn.zopim.com/?11THLdRhqxNgdgRiWyGwwAv8e4KF6S6G';z.t=+new Date;$. type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
     </script> <!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that its a browser compatibility issue  Upgrade and try other IE version hope it works. If the problem is still remain you can communicate with zopim help support team.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. In IE8 there is no  flash player, that why it didn't show the zopim layout. Now I installed flash player. So it works fine now. Really thanks for the answer :)

As a new user, You answered for my question. Its very great. +1 for the answer